# log unclosed PreparedStatement using c3p0

Tags: java, c3p0

Using c3p0 I can log unclosed `Connection` by setting properties `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` and 
`unreturnedConnectionTimeout`. I wonder if is there any way to find out unclosed `PreparedStatement` because today I found a code as below:

```
...
ps=dbConnection.prepareStatement(qry);
rs=ps.executeQuery();   
if(!rsCandItem.next())//to check Result Set has rows
{
rs.close();
qry = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1";
ps=dbConnection.prepareStatement(qry); //same PreparedStatement object is used without closing previous instance
rs=ps.executeQuery();
}
...
```

I guess using same `PreparedStatement` object (ps) without closing it is wrong/bad practice, correct me if I am wrong. So I want to log using c3p0 (or by any other way) unclosed `PreparedStatement`. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the driver is broken, closing a `Connection` should also close associated statements and `ResultSets`. As you said, it is bad practice to not close them even if in particular cases they might not cause problems.

Since connection pools deal with `Connections` (and they're the ones that **will** leak resources), it's unlikely that there are settings for observing anything else.

Comment: So there is no way to find out such bad practice followed in existing project. I have to go through each code only?

Comment: You can try something like findbugs or other tools, to see if they can identify unclosed resources.